# Jmeter threadgroup sharing counter between threads

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to create a Thread Group in jmeter to create users and their devices with many (for example 5000) devices.

I have no problem to create this test and I want to have the name of the users and device in a correlative order.

```
1. user1--device1 
2. user2--device2
3. user3--device3
```

I already created the test but to create 5000 users and devices in the same Thread Group I need to run 5000 iterations with 3 requests each, using 1 thread, because otherwise I have the same user name repeated by multiple threads (for example with 3 threads)

```
1. user1--device1 
2. user2--device2 
3. user3--device3 
4. user1--device1
5. user2--device2
6. user3--device3
7. user1--device1
8. user2--device2    
9. user3--device3
```

My question is: is there any way to share the loop counter between threads in order to create 5000 users/devices with more than one thread (for example 20 threads). 
This will help me a lot because instead of waiting for 20 minutes, it will be a minute to create the users.

Many thanks!

http://pastebin.com/S1izFC9r

Added explanation I want for example maximun 9 devices (counter_max) but I want to run it with 3 threads. I want the result be like that

1. thread1--user1-device1
2. thread2--user2--device2
3. thread3--user3--device3
4. thread1--user4--device4
5. thread2--user5--device5
6. thread3--user6--device6
7. thread1--user7--device7
8. thread2--user8--device8
9. thread3--user9--device9

Comment: Sure, just have a Counter with "Track counter independently for each user" **unchecked** and it will track counter for all threads. Or share your plan to see what you are currently doing.

Comment: I had simplified the script at maximum in order to copy here. It only create tenants (users). The order part is not a problem. I want to create consecutive tenants in different threads. I just attached the file

Comment: As I told you earlier, you need to uncheck  "Track counter independently for each user" option in the counter. In your script I can see that it's checked: `<boolProp name="CounterConfig.per_user">true</boolProp>`

Comment: I had already try with this to false before put the reply and it doesn't work. I will try again in one hour when I arrive to home. many thanks!

Comment: Hello Kiril, I already try and the counter works at the same, I want to make for example. I think I am not well explained what I want. 
if I put for example max counter to 3 and I have 3 threads in the thread group I want it to work like (added to general question)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can implement it using [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function in **"global"** mode, like: `${__counter(FALSE,)}`

- `__counter()` function returns incremented value each time it's being called
- in the "global" mode counter value is shared across threads

[image: Counter Global Demo]

So you should be able to use as many threads as required and each thread will use the next counter value to create your users and devices with multiple threads.

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article for comprehensive information on using "counter" config element and function.

Comment: Thank your, that was I was expecting ;)